# Flipping switch (by itself) trips breaker

Tags: switch, circuit-breaker, 240v

I have a 30A 240V circuit breaker I have added to the panel to run a saw. From the breaker, it goes to a switch on the wall, which is high enough that the kids cannot reach. Using a multimeter, I have 240v at the breaker. When the switch is in the off position, I have 204v on circuit A of the switch. *With nothing on circuit B*, when I flip the switch to "on", it trips the breaker. 0V on circuit A and 0V at the breaker (well... 0.05v is what it actually reads).

I thought I had a faulty switch, so I replaced it. But, new switch does the same thing.

The wiring diagram is simple... but accurately reflects what I have done ... it's not complicated.

White is going into "line" (brass connector) on the switch, and black is going into "load" (dark connector).

What am I doing wrong here?

```
                                      Circuit A
    +------+           White            +---+
    |      +----------------------------+   |
    |Breaker                            | + | Switch
    |      +----------------------------+   |
    +------+           Black            +---+
                                        |
         +------------------------------+
                      Ground
```

Note: This question was suggested during review: [20amp breaker trips with NO load...Continuity between black & white wire at electrical box](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/49379/20amp-breaker-trips-with-no-load-continuity-between-black-white-wire-at-elec) and the common wisdom here is that the problem would  be between the panel and the switch. This wire is brand new, and already sealed in conduit. I would have to rip everything out, and re-do 8 hours of work to re-run everything if this is the case. I am hoping it's something else simple that I have missed.

Comment: When the switch is flipped and causes the breaker to trip, is there any sound (besides the switch) like a *bzzzzzt*, or *zzzzapppp*, or explosion?

Comment: Photos of the wiring inside the switch box and wiring inside the outlet box might expedite understanding the problem.

Comment: When you say "sealed" in conduit, it it actually _sealed_ (as in there's something blocking the ends of the conduit), or did you just pull wire through conduit and the conduit is now buried behind drywall (or other wall covering)? _Normally_, you could pull new wire through existing conduit if it comes to that... (Not fun for a brand new install, but far nicer than tearing up walls.)

Comment: You write "added to the panel to run a saw" - but where's the saw in your diagram (or the outlet you plan to use)? All you show us is the breaker to a switch ...

Comment: Because the saw was irrelevant.

Comment: Sealed in conduit means PVC grey cement already used to bond the PVC together. It goes out the garage wall, and is buried along side the house until it gets to the wall where the panel is, which is also where all the AC boxes are, so it's convenient to go in through there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong here?

You have created a short circuit. When you close the switch, power flows with no load (other than the wires themselves) and the circuit breaker trips to prevent a fire.

You’ll need a double-pole switch (two “line” input connections and two “load” output connections to disconnect this 240V circuit.

Do not re-use the old switch elsewhere. It is likely damaged inside now.

Comment: I got thrown off because the color coded screws on the switch (and the instructions that showed circuit A and B as being on the left and right) made me think I should wire the line on the left and load on the right. Instead, line was at the top (both brass screws) and load was at the bottom (both dark). I was creating a short across the switch instead of interrupting both circuits at the same time.